# Apache Beam - Unable to infer a Coder on a DoFn with multiple output tags

Tags: java-8, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to execute a pipeline using Apache Beam but I get an error when trying to put some output tags:

```
import com.google.cloud.Tuple;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.FixedWindows;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.Window;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TupleTag;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TupleTagList;
import org.joda.time.Duration;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * The Transformer.
 */
class Transformer {
    final static TupleTag<Map<String, String>> successfulTransformation = new TupleTag<>();
    final static TupleTag<Tuple<String, String>> failedTransformation = new TupleTag<>();

    /**
     * The entry point of the application.
     *
     * @param args the input arguments
     */
    public static void main(String... args) {
        TransformerOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
                .withValidation()
                .as(TransformerOptions.class);

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        p.apply("Input", PubsubIO
                .readMessagesWithAttributes()
                .withIdAttribute("id")
                .fromTopic(options.getTopicName()))
                .apply(Window.<PubsubMessage>into(FixedWindows
                        .of(Duration.standardSeconds(60))))
                .apply("Transform",
                        ParDo.of(new JsonTransformer())
                                .withOutputTags(successfulTransformation,
                                        TupleTagList.of(failedTransformation)));

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }

    /**
     * Deserialize the input and convert it to a key-value pairs map.
     */
    static class JsonTransformer extends DoFn<PubsubMessage, Map<String, String>> {

        /**
         * Process each element.
         *
         * @param c the processing context
         */
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            String messagePayload = new String(c.element().getPayload());
            try {
                Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
                }.getType();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(messagePayload, type);
                c.output(map);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Failed to process input {} -- adding to dead letter file", c.element(), e);
                String attributes = c.element()
                        .getAttributeMap()
                        .entrySet().stream().map((entry) ->
                                String.format("%s -> %s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining());
                c.output(failedTransformation, Tuple.of(attributes, messagePayload));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The error shown is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
>   return a default Coder for Transform.out1 [PCollection]. Correct one
>   of the following root causes: No Coder has been manually specified; 
>   you may do so using .setCoder().   Inferring a Coder from the
>   CoderRegistry failed: Unable to provide a Coder for V. Building a
>   Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed. See suppressed
>   exceptions for detailed failures. Using the default output Coder from
>   the producing PTransform failed: Unable to provide a Coder for V.
>   Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.

I tried different ways to fix the issue but I think I just do not understand what is the problem. I know that these lines cause the error to happen:

```
.withOutputTags(successfulTransformation,TupleTagList.of(failedTransformation))
```

but I do not get which part of it, what part needs a specific Coder and what is "V" in the error (from "Unable to provide a Coder for V").

Why is the error happening? I also tried to look at Apache Beam's docs but they do not seems to explain such a usage nor I understand much from the section discussing about coders.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, I would suggest the following -- change:

```
final static TupleTag<Map<String, String>> successfulTransformation = 
    new TupleTag<>();
final static TupleTag<Tuple<String, String>> failedTransformation = 
    new TupleTag<>();
```

into this:

```
final static TupleTag<Map<String, String>> successfulTransformation = 
    new TupleTag<Map<String, String>>() {};
final static TupleTag<Tuple<String, String>> failedTransformation = 
    new TupleTag<Tuple<String, String>>() {};
```

That should help the coder inference determine the type of the side output. Also, have you properly registered a `CoderProvider` for `Tuple`?

Comment: The change does not appear to do anything at the current stage. And no, I have not registered a CoderProvider for Tuple as it's not clear to me what is the way I am supposed to do it, would you be able to give more info?

Comment: I replaced `Tuple` with a class made by myself which extends Serializable and your answer solved my issue. Why? What changes between what I did and what you suggested? Also do you have any guess on why Google Cloud's `Tuple` does not extends `Serializable` and can't be inherited?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Cloud's Tuple. Can you link to where it came from? Generally, using Serializable is going to be less efficient than using a custom coder, or something like Avro because of Java serialization. See the documentation on [registering Coders](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#data-encoding-and-type-safety).

Comment: The reason why has to do with Java generics and erasure. Within the SDK we need to figure out the types in order to infer which Coder to use. `new TupleTag<>()` has no type information after erasure, which makes this impossible. `new TupleTag<String>() {}` actually creates an anonymous subclass with no generic arguments, which allows us to play tricks with reflection and determine that the actual type is `String`, which then lets us look up `Coder<String>`.

Comment: Anyway Google Cloud's `Tuple` is very simple: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.25.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/Tuple.html

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Ben Chambers' answer, Kotlin is:

```
val successTag = object : TupleTag<MyObj>() {}
val deadLetterTag = object : TupleTag<String>() {}
```